# programming with short-circuit evaluation in Java

Tags: java, short-circuiting

Does relying on short-circuit evaluation make the code fragile?
I wrote a piece of code that essentially looks like the following. My professor wanted me to rewrite it.

(Note: I know for sure that only one of the four conditions will be true, because given any stream, there is only one 'next token', right?)

```
foo getFoo()
{
        Bar bar;
        if ((bar = peekAndGet('x')) != null 
                || (bar = peekAndGet('y')) != null 
                || (bar = peekAndGet('z')) != null 
                || (bar = peekAndGet('t')) != null) 
            return produce(bar);
        else 
            return null;
}
```

Is this really fragile? I find it working perfectly. But how should I rewrite it?

Comment: If it works as expected, handles boundary cases, is easily understood, and is easily expandable, it's good code. "good practice" will help you get there, but what matters are the criteria I laid out.

Comment: can you provide peekAndGet method?

Comment: I think it's gross to do assignment and comparison in the same line... But that's just me (and a lot of other people).

Comment: @jahroy It's also... **the** construct to use when reading from a stream. I also like C#'s `return _foo ?? (_foo = InitFoo());` lazy initialization construct. (Although that's for want of a `?=` operator.)

Comment: @millimoose - Are you saying that it is **the correct** construct or **the most popular** construct?  I always thought it was a something used by one-time C programmers using Java.

Comment: @jahroy It is correct in that it works correctly, yes. It is also terse, and clearly communicates "until the end of the stream is reached" as the loop condition, where the alternative sans an assignment expression would split the idea up on several lines and require adding a `break;`. So, yeah, to me avoiding this construct (when it can't be replaced with higher-level code, e.g. iterating over lines of text) seems like oblivious pedanticism.

Comment: @millimoose - Ok... I think I see what you mean.  You're referring to the example above, in which case your comment makes perfect sense (as there is no real way to avoid assign/compare in the same line without getting messy).  I can't disagree with you there.  I guess my point was that I would strive to write it like assylias does in his suggestion (if it makes it easier to read/understand).

Comment: @jahroy Oh, right. Yes, I wasn't talking about the OP's case (a loop is certainly more appropriate here), I was just objecting to rejecting the language feature out of hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would refactor it and write it like this:

```
char[] values = {'x', 'y', 'z', 't'};
for (char c : values) {
    Bar bar = peekAndGet(c);
    if (bar != null) return produce(bar);
}
return null;
```

Note: one good reason to do it, is that the first time I read your code I thought it looked buggy until I read your question. You want to keep those "Something looks wrong" moments for things that really are wrong.

Comment: Hah, that actually looks good, thanks!(Strage it never occurred to me... Maybe it did, but I automatically rejected it because I always though loops added a lot of overhead)

Comment: @OneTwoThree That's microoptimization, which might not necessarily be warranted. (Even when parsing, you probably spend more time doing higher-level semantic analysis later.) And for all you know, the JVM JIT is capable of unrolling this loop to optimize it for you.

Answer (score 1):

you are initializing your Bar object inside the if statement, try initializing it outside the if statement.

Comment: I can't do that. How should I initialise it to?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the short-circuiting alone that's the problem. It's short-circuiting plus side effects that's probably the target. It's widely frowned upon because it makes code harder to understand and easier to break. In your case, it's a little less onerous, but take this example:

```
if ((b && c++ > 1) || (c++ < 10)) { ... }
```

Who can possibly keep track of what's happening to `c` in a case like that?

Answer (score 1):

The code is not in the least bit fragile. Its behavior is completely specified by the Java Language Specification, and does what I think you intend.

Having multiple side-effects, especially multiple assignments to the same variable, can make code less readable, and is discouraged in the JLS.